# Can't rewrite the data at file starting but I can apped at the End in append mode in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I want to store student information in a file in C, I choose to write in a binary file format.first I had written all student data to the file in write mode. first 4 bytes(int) represents the num of students and then subsequent data is for storing student Information.

when I want to append some more student data to the file, I can apped the student data at the end of file in append mode but could not update the no of students at the start of file (first 4 bytes(int)) which are already written in write mode. There is no where stated in manpages that I can't rewrite the data that are already written in write mode. Below is the code. Thanks in advance.

```
typedef struct
{
    char* rollNo;
    char* name;
    char* grade;
}Student;

int numStudents;

void append(Student* newStudent){
    
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen("students.bin","ab"))==NULL){ f_err_report(ERR_OPEN);exit(1);}
    
    //appending the new student at the end of the file
    
    // writing rollNo

    int len;
    len = strlen(newStudent->rollNo)+1;

    if(fwrite(&len,sizeof(int),1,fp)!=1) {
        f_err_report(ERR_WRITE);

    }
    if(fwrite(newStudent->rollNo,sizeof(char)*len,1,fp)!=1) {
        f_err_report(ERR_WRITE);

    }


    //writing name

    len = strlen(newStudent->name)+1;

    if(fwrite(&len,sizeof(int),1,fp)!=1) {
        f_err_report(ERR_WRITE);

    }
    if(fwrite(newStudent->name,sizeof(char)*len,1,fp)!=1) {
        f_err_report(ERR_WRITE);

    }

    //writing grade

    len = strlen(newStudent]->grade)+1;

    if(fwrite(&len,sizeof(int),1,fp)!=1) {
        f_err_report(ERR_WRITE);

    }
    if(fwrite(newStudent->grade,sizeof(char)*len,1,fp)!=1) {
        f_err_report(ERR_WRITE);

    }


    //updating the total number of students at the file starting. But this doesn't happen!!! It stays same as when I wrote in "write mode" previously

  numStudents++;

    rewind(fp);

    if(fwrite(&numStudents,sizeof(int),1,fp)!=1){
        f_err_report(ERR_WRITE);
    }
    printf("appended to the list \n");


    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean "I don't know whether I can", as in "I have neither read the documentation nor tried it"?  In that case, please do both first, and update your question to reflect your new-found knowledge.  Otherwise, please update the question to describe what you expected and why, and what you actually observed.

Comment: I had gone through the man pages. It only states -  Opening a file in append mode (a as the first character of mode)
       causes all subsequent write operations to this stream to occur at
       end-of-file, as if preceded the call:

           fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_END);

Comment: But there Is no where stated like you can't write at the start of file using fseek(stream,0,SEEK_SET) or rewind(fp) in append mode. I think what I code  should work

Comment: And yet, I can only assume that you're asking because you find that your program *doesn't* work.  So you already know that the answer is "no, it doesn't work like that."  I don't understand how you interpret "all subsequent write operations [...] occur at end-of-file" as affording write operations somewhere other than at the end of the file, but however you came to that conclusion, it is wrong.  If you want to be able to write at any position in the file then open it in regular write (`w`) mode, not append mode.  Or in `r+` mode if you don't want the file's initial contents removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I want to append some more student data to the file, I can apped the student data at the end of file in append mode but could not update the no of students at the start of file (first 4 bytes(int)) which are already written in write mode. There is no where stated in manpages that I can't rewrite the data that are already written in write mode.

[Yes there is](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p6):

> Opening a file with append mode ('a' as the first character in the mode argument) causes all subsequent writes to the file to be forced to the then current end-of-file, regardless of intervening calls to the fseek function.

And from [the Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html):

> Opening a file in append mode (a as the first character of mode)
> causes all subsequent write operations to this stream to occur at
> end-of-file, as if preceded the call:
>
> ```
>       fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_END);
> ```

The only way on POSIX systems to open a file in append mode but still be able to write to any position in a file is to use the [POSIX `open()` call](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/open.html) with the `O_APPEND` flag and then use the [POSIX `pwrite()` call](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/pwrite.html) to write to the desired location:

> The `pwrite()` function shall be equivalent to `write()`, except that it writes into a given position and does not change the file offset (regardless of whether `O_APPEND` is set).

[But `pwrite()` is broken on Linux](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html#BUGS):

> POSIX requires that opening a file with the `O_APPEND` flag should
> have no effect on the location at which `pwrite()` writes data.
> However, on Linux, if a file is opened with `O_APPEND`, `pwrite()`
> appends data to the end of the file, regardless of the value of
> offset.

Answer (score 2):

When you called

```
rewind(fp);
```

you successfully reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file, ready to update the number of student records.  All right so far.

But then you called

```
fwrite(&numStudents, sizeof(int), 1, fp)
```

to actually update the number of records.  And since the file is opened in append mode, this translates implicitly to the equivalent of

```
fseek(fp, OL, SEEK_END);
fwrite(&numStudents, sizeof(int), 1, fp)
```

That is, in append mode, every time you write to the file, there's an automatic seek to the end of the file, followed by the write you asked for.

So your `rewind()` call accomplishes nothing in the long run, because it's undone by the next write.

Once upon a time, calling `fopen` with `"a"` mode basically just opened the file, and seeked to the end once.  In those days, your code would have worked as you expected.  But not any more.  In your case, you want to use `"w"` mode (or `"w+"` or `"r+"`, if you want to both read and write), and when you want to append a new record at the end, call

```
fseek(fp, OL, SEEK_END);
```

to explicitly get to the end when you need to.